# Mock Node module with a callback function

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have some code that uses [ssh-exec](https://github.com/mafintosh/ssh-exec), a node module, in its callback form.

```
const sshExec = require('ssh-exec');

const myCodeThatUsesSshExec = (arg1,arg2,arg3) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  sshExec('ls -lh', 'ubuntu@my-remote.com', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
  if(err) {
    reject(err);
  } else if(stderr) {
    reject(stderr);
  } else {
   // process stdout
   const results = process stdout into an array...
   resolve(results);
  }
})
});
```

I am trying to test my code and I can't figure out how to mock the callback function to return mock data. Here's my attempt so far -

```
const myCodeThatUsesSshExec = require('./my-code');
jest.mock('ssh-exec');

test('ssh test', async () => {
    const resp = `total 268K
-rw-rw-rw- 1 bob bob 369 Jun 12 15:00 Dockerfile
-rw-rw-rw- 1 bob bob 849 Jun 12 14:46 app.js
drwxr-xr-x 1 bob bob 4.0K Jun 12 10:01 bin
-rw-rw-rw- 1 bob bob 49 Jun 15 14:34 jest.config.js`;

  // I know this doesn't work, just trying to illustrate what I'm trying to do.
    sshExec.mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve(resp));

  const received = await myCodeThatUsesSshExec(1,2,3);
  expect(received).toEqual(['Dockerfile', 'app.js', 'bin', 'jest.config.js']);

});
```

How do I mock the ssh-exec callback?

Comment: That test doesn't align at all with how you're using `exec` - the subject doesn't actually *return* anything. If you're mocking `exec` you need to think about how to test it got the right arguments, *including* the callback. Exercising the callback is going to mean output to `console.log` as shown, *not* a value being returned to assert on.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Take a look now, the original was just an example from their docs to illustrate the callback form of using their api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that you *don't* mock the callback, because that's part of the subject you're trying to test. Your current test doesn't work because `ssh-exec` *doesn't* return a promise; it accepts and invokes a callback. In general, test doubles need to match the interface of the things they replace.

Instead, use your mocked `ssh-exec` to invoke the *real* callback:

```js
const sshExec = require('ssh-exec');

const myCodeThatUsesSshExec = require('./my-code');

jest.mock('ssh-exec');

test('ssh test', async () => {
    const resp = `total 268K
-rw-rw-rw- 1 bob bob 369 Jun 12 15:00 Dockerfile
-rw-rw-rw- 1 bob bob 849 Jun 12 14:46 app.js
drwxr-xr-x 1 bob bob 4.0K Jun 12 10:01 bin
-rw-rw-rw- 1 bob bob 49 Jun 15 14:34 jest.config.js`;

  // you can't await here, because it will block until the callback is invoked...
  const promise = myCodeThatUsesSshExec(1, 2, 3);

  // assert on the call to ssh-exec
  expect(sshExec).toHaveBeenCalledWith('ls -lh', 'ubuntu@my-remote.com', expect.any(Function));

  // invoke the callback, which is the third argument to the first call
  sshExec.mock.calls[0][2](null, resp);

  // assert on the result
  expect(await promise).toEqual(['Dockerfile', 'app.js', 'bin', 'jest.config.js']);
  // or you can remove async from this test case and use:
  // expect(promise).resolves.toEqual(['Dockerfile', 'app.js', 'bin', 'jest.config.js']);
});
```

---

Alternatively, make your own wrapper for `ssh-exec` that better matches your use case:

```js
const sshPromise = (...args) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  sshExec(...args, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (err) {
      reject(err);
    } else if (stderr) {
      reject(stderr);
    } else {
      resolve(stdout);
    }
  });
});
```

Now you can mock this simpler interface, which you own, and your original test will work as expected.

It also simplifies the consuming code:

```
const myCodeThatUsesSshExec = (arg1, arg2, arg3) => sshPromise('ls -lh', 'ubuntu@my-remote.com')
  .then((stdout) => {
    // process stdout
    const results = process stdout into an array...
    return results;
  });
```

Comment: This is great, I really like the second version, but wouldn't I want to test ssh-promise as well?

Comment: @user210757 yes, you do want to test that facade, but not at the unit level. The details depend on the larger context, but e.g. an integration test with a known test directory would allow you to check that the overall result was correct. The danger with mocking what you *don't* own (ssh-exec in this case) is that you may not find out until too late if that interface or behaviour changes, because *the mock still works fine*.