Unable to get coverage for callback functions passed from argument in jest
My use case layer in nestjs look like below
export class AddModuleUseCases {
constructor(
    private readonly logger: ILogger,
    private readonly i18n: I18nService,
    private readonly moduleRepository: IModuleRepository,
    private readonly exceptionsService: ExceptionsService,
    private readonly httpService: HttpService,
) {}

async execute(content: ModuleModel, userLanguage): Promise<AddModuleResponseDto> {
    try {
        this.logger.log('addBerthBookingUseCases execute : Inserting new record for Berth Booking');

        const existingBooking = await this.moduleRepository.findById(content.id);

        if (existingBooking) {
            this.exceptionsService.DataAlreadyExistException(
                `${errorConstants.DT_ERR_1016[userLanguage.toUpperCase()]}`,
                HttpStatus.CONFLICT,
            );
        }

        const callbacksBeforeInsert = [
            async () => {
                const res = await this.httpService.axiosRef.get('http://127.0.0.1:1337');
                this.logger.log(`Response 1 BEFORE insertion: ${res.data}`);
            },
            async () => {
                const res = await this.httpService.axiosRef.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
                this.logger.log(`Response 2 BEFORE insertion: ${res.data}`);
            },
        ];

        const callbacksAfterInsert = [
            async () => {
                const res = await this.httpService.axiosRef.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
                this.logger.log(`Response 1 AFTER insertion: ${res.data}`);
            },
            async () => {
                const res = await this.httpService.axiosRef.get('http://127.0.0.1:1337');
                this.logger.log(`Response 2 AFTER insertion: ${res.data}`);
            },
        ];

        const insertOptions = [
            {
                entityTarget: ENTITIES.BERTHBOOKING,
                insertionData: content,
                callBeforeInsert: callbacksBeforeInsert,
                callAfterInsert: callbacksAfterInsert,
            },
        ];

        const newModuleData = await this.moduleRepository.insert(insertOptions);

        const localizationMessage = this.i18n.t(LocalizationKeys.MODULE_POST_SUCCESS, userLanguage);

        const result = new AddModuleResponseDto(
            newModuleData,
            LocalizationKeys.MODULE_POST_SUCCESS,
            localizationMessage,
            userLanguage,
        );

        return result;
    } catch (error) {
        this.logger.error(`deleteBerthBookingUseCases execute : Error inserting the Booking : ${error}`);

        this.exceptionsService.internalServerErrorException({
            message: error,
            code_error: HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.toString(),
        });
    }
}
}

and I have written spec for that, but unable to cover some lines. I have tried some options but was not able to get coverage for this
describe('AddModuleUseCases', () => {
let logger: ILogger;
let i18n: I18nService;
let moduleRepository: IModuleRepository;
let exceptionsService: ExceptionsService;
let httpService: HttpService;
let useCase: AddModuleUseCases;

beforeEach(() => {
    logger = { log: jest.fn(), error: jest.fn() } as unknown as ILogger;

    i18n = { t: jest.fn() } as unknown as I18nService;

    moduleRepository = {
        findById: jest.fn(),
        insert: jest.fn(),
    } as unknown as IModuleRepository;

    exceptionsService = {
        DataAlreadyExistException: jest.fn(),
        internalServerErrorException: jest.fn(),
    } as unknown as ExceptionsService;

    httpService = new HttpService();

    useCase = new AddModuleUseCases(logger, i18n, moduleRepository, exceptionsService, httpService);
});

afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
});

describe('execute', () => {
    const content = addBerthBookingMockData as ModuleModel;
    const userLanguage = 'en';

    it('successfully insert a new module and returns response', async () => {
        const responseData = { data: 'Success' };
        const mockInsertOptions = [
            {
                entityTarget: ENTITIES.BERTHBOOKING,
                insertionData: addBerthBookingMockData,
                callBeforeInsert: [
                    async () => {
                        const res = await httpService.axiosRef.get('http://127.0.0.1:1337');
                        logger.log(`Response 1 BEFORE insertion: ${res.data}`);
                    },
                    async () => {
                        const res = await httpService.axiosRef.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
                        logger.log(`Response 2 BEFORE insertion: ${res.data}`);
                    },
                ],
                callAfterInsert: [
                    async () => {
                        const res = await httpService.axiosRef.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
                        logger.log(`Response 1 AFTER insertion: ${res.data}`);
                    },
                    async () => {
                        const res = await httpService.axiosRef.get('http://127.0.0.1:1337');
                        logger.log(`Response 2 AFTER insertion: ${res.data}`);
                    },
                ],
            },
        ];

        jest.spyOn(httpService.axiosRef, 'get').mockResolvedValue(responseData);
        jest.spyOn(moduleRepository, 'findById').mockResolvedValue(null);
        const insertedData = jest.spyOn(moduleRepository, 'insert').mockResolvedValueOnce(content);
        jest.spyOn(i18n, 't').mockReturnValue('Module added successfully.');

        const result = await useCase.execute(content, userLanguage);

        expect(moduleRepository.findById).toHaveBeenCalledWith(content.id);
        expect(insertedData).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(i18n.t).toHaveBeenCalledWith(LocalizationKeys.MODULE_POST_SUCCESS, userLanguage);
        expect(result).toBeInstanceOf(AddModuleResponseDto);
        expect(result).toEqual({
            data: content,
            localization: {
                keys: { 'berth-bookings.post.success': 'Module added successfully.' },
                'accept-language': 'en',
            },
        } as AddModuleResponseDto);
    });

    it('throws DataAlreadyExistException if module already exists', async () => {
        jest.spyOn(moduleRepository, 'findById').mockResolvedValue(content);

        const result = await useCase.execute(content, userLanguage);

        expect(result).toEqual({
            data: undefined,
            localization: { keys: { 'berth-bookings.post.success': undefined }, 'accept-language': 'en' },
        });
        expect(exceptionsService.DataAlreadyExistException).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
            errorConstants.DT_ERR_1016[userLanguage.toUpperCase()],
            HttpStatus.CONFLICT,
        );
    });

    it('handles errors from the repository and services', async () => {
        const error = new Error('Internal server error');
        jest.spyOn(moduleRepository, 'findById').mockRejectedValue(error);

        expect(await useCase.execute(content, userLanguage)).toBeUndefined();
        expect(logger.error).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(exceptionsService.internalServerErrorException).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
});

I was not able to get coverage for the callback statements passed in the parameter for the insert


Those callbacks are all passed to moduleRepository.insert(insertOptions), whose implementation is... jest.fn(), which doesn't do anything with any of its arguments except store them. So it shouldn't be surprising they're not called. (One example of calling callbacks a mock receives: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62412831/3001761.)

Thank you @jonrsharpe for your comment, it helped in achieving, sharing the code below which got it working
jest.spyOn(moduleRepository, 'insert').mockImplementation(
            async (insertOptions: TransactionalDataType<ModuleModel>[]) => {
                // Here, manually trigger callbacks or modify data
                insertOptions.forEach((option) => {
                    option.callBeforeInsert.forEach((cb) => cb());
                    option.callAfterInsert.forEach((cb) => cb());
                });
                // Return the desired mock value
                return addBerthBookingMockData;
            },
        );

